# Not able to write the function to know the Equi-width binning in Excel

Tags: excel, width

I'm using Excel to know the Equi-width and i wrote this function in Excel but it's not working :(

```
=IF((A2<=37),"bin1",IF(A2<=56),"bin2","bin3")
```

Any solution pleasee

Comment: whats your min and max value?

Comment: I think bzimor answer solves your problem. It is correct solution.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
=IF(A2<=56,IF(A2<=37,"bin1","bin2"),"bin3")
```

If you fail, try [my file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1eUtQWE5tdFgybUU)

Comment: It's not working too :( no result only the same formula you wrote it .. any idea? :/

Comment: Not same, If value in `A2` is `53` `(53<56)` then it checks if it is less or equal to `37` `(53>37)` then writes `bin2`. If value is 80 then result will be `bin3`. If value is `30` `(30<56)` then result will be `bin1`

Comment: Did you want this?

Comment: I know but when i wrote this formula, nothing happens in the cell , only its shows " IF(A2<=56,IF(A2<=37,"bin1","bin2"),"bin3")" not any results at all, and this happens when i wrote these types of functions ,, any idea why am i facing this issue?

Comment: Aha, Change number format of cell `Text` to `General` : http://www.accountingweb.com/sites/default/files/Text---Figure-1.png to this :http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/175/3_number_format_box.png

Comment: Add equal sign `=` in front of formula :)

Comment: And thats what happened when i wrote my formula : https://postimg.org/image/8aul43o8d/

Comment: @dana, check my file

Comment: umm can you please tell me which file? and where?

Comment: In my answer or here is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1eUtQWE5tdFgybUU   Download it and use

Comment: Yayy it works, thank youu veryy much for taking the time to help me

Comment: Please, provide your example. then we can try

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciated